# I am getting Parse error while parsing json when the key is a number

Tags: java, javascript, json, parsing

I am getting my result as json from a java application.That is in the following form

```
 1: {
        "CONGESTION": 1,
        "ANSWER": 7
    }
```

Here `1` is `Long` type in java.

Then i am getting parse error.But when i return like as follows

```
 "1": {
        "CONGESTION": 1,
        "ANSWER": 7
    }
```

Then i am not getting any error.Here `1` is `String` type in java.

Is it mandatory to have string type as keys.What is the problem with Long type key.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: You should use a JSON library.  Do not build JSON by hand.

Comment: The JSON standard dictates that keys must be strings: http://json.org/.

Comment: @SLaks json library?can u suggest any library?

Comment: @PSR Jackson or Gson in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keys in JSON must *always* be quoted.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: You're right; clarified.  (and bools and `null`)